# How to import data into rails models from a table in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following schema in my rails app:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161020060112) do     
 create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "languages", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end 

 create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.date     "date"
   t.string   "body"
   t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
   t.integer  "author_id"
   t.integer  "language_id"
   t.integer  "source_id"
   t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_author_id"
   t.index ["language_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_language_id"
   t.index ["source_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_source_id"
 end

  create_table "source_types", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sources", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
   t.integer  "source_type_id"
   t.index ["source_type_id"], name: "index_sources_on_source_type_id"
  end
end
```

And this is the schema of the table that I want to import data from:

```
CREATE TABLE quotation_data(
 id integer primary key,
 author_name text,
 source_type text,
 source text,
 language text, 
 date text,
 title text,
 body text
);
```

I did find some posts on Stackoverflow but none that tell about importing data from a single table into fields distributed over many models.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have imported data from database I create the list that list everything that I have inserted in the database.

like:

Under *controller#show*

```
def show
  @quotes = Quote.all
end
```

*views#show*

```
   <ul> 
     <% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
       <li>
         <%= link_to quotes.title, edit_quotes_path(quote) %>
       </li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
```

This will help you to view what is on the database and edit it also.